# Is math within macro computed at compile time?

Tags: c, macros, build-process

For example, does `MIN_N_THINGIES` below compile to 2?  Or will I recompute the division every time I use the macro in code (e.g. recomputing the end condition of a for loop each iteration).

```
#define MAX_N_THINGIES  (10)
#define MIN_N_THINGIES  ((MAX_N_THINGIES) / 5)

uint8_t i;
for (i = 0; i < MIN_N_THINGIES; i++) {
  printf("hi");
}
```

This question stems from the fact that I'm still learning about the build process.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you pass -E to gcc it will show what the preprocessor stage outputted.

`gcc -E test.c | tail -n11`

Outputs:

```
# 3 "test.c" 2

int main() {
uint8_t i;
for (i = 0; i < ((10) / 5); i++) {
  printf("hi");
}
return 0;
}
```

Then if you pass -s flag to gcc you will see that the division was optimized out.  If you also pass the -o flag you can set the output files and diff them to see that they generated the same code.

```
gcc -S test.c -o test-with-div.s
edit test.c to make MIN_N_THINGIES equal a const 2
gcc -S test.c -o test-constant.s
diff test-with-div.s test-constant.s
// for educational purposes you should look at the .s files generated.
```

Then as mentioned in another comment you can change the optimization flag by using -O...

`gcc -S test.c -O2 -o test-unroll-loop.s`

Will unroll the for loop even such that there isn't even a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor will replace `MIN_N_THINGIES` with `((10)/5)`, then it is up to the compiler to optimize  ( or not ) the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. The standard does not mandate that it is or it is not. On most compilers it will do after passing optimization flags (for example gcc with `-O0` does not do it while with `-O2` it even unrolls the loop).

Modern compilers perform even much more complicated techniques (vectorization, loop skewing,  blocking ...). However unless you really care about performance, for ex. you program HPC, program real time system etc., you probably should not care about the output of the compiler - unless you're just interested (and yes - compilers can be a fascinating subject).

Comment: it's actually for a bare-metal project, so i'm interested in basic optimization, nothing super fancy right now

Comment: @tarabyte, then your question is the wrong one, for the moment, premature optimization.

Comment: @JensGustedt, i disagree that the question is wrong.  i'm trying to learn about this problem in general.

Answer (score 1):

No. The preprocessor does not calculate macros, they're handled by the compiler. The preprocessor can calculate arithmetic expressions (no floating point values) in #if conditionals though.

Macros are simply text substitutions.

Note that the expanded macros can still be calculated and optimized by the compiler, it's just that it's not done by the preprocessor.

Comment: You are right that preprocessor won't substitute but compiler will (usually) perform constant folding.

Comment: Right. :) I was just about to add that. Apparently the boost libraries can perform preprocessor arithmetic on non floating point values, as well.

Answer (score 0):

The standard mandates that some expressions are evaluated at compile time. But note that the preprocessor does just text splicing (well, almost) when the macro is called, so if you do:

```
#define A(x) ((x) / (S))

#define S  5

A(10) /* Gives ((10) / (5)) == 2 */

#undef S
#define S  2

A(20)  /* Gives ((20) / (2)) == 10 */
```

The parenteses are to avoid idiocies like:

```
#define square(x) x * x

square(a + b)  /* Gets you a + b * a + b, not the expected square */
```

After preprocessing, the result is passed to the compiler proper, which does (most of) the computation in the source that the standard requests. Most compilers will do a lot of *constant folding*, i.e., computing (sub)expressions made of known constants, as this is simple to do.

To see the expansions, it is useful to write a `*.c` file of a few lines, just with the macros to check, and run it just through the preprocessor (typically someting like `cc -E file.c`) and check the output.

Comment: yes, i'll just build and inspect assembly after compilation.  unfortunately not able to use gcc here, so i'll have to figure out how  preserve the output at each stage